# Categories overriding methods in UIViewControllers not working - method never called

Tags: objective-c, categories

I have an iPad 3 app that I want to only be viewable in landescape mode. I have a few UIViewContoller subclasses (it is a really simple app), and in all of them I have the following code:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight;
}
```

The code is not big, but duplicated, and I would like to learn ways one can avoid this in Objective-C. I read about categories, and how they can override methods from classes / instances they apply to, so decided to try. I used the Xcode wizard to create a LandscapeOnly category for a UIViewController class, and moved the above implementation to it - to no avail. I tried adding the method signature to the header file, but this also didn't change anything.

How is this done? How can I use categories to override instance methods?

I read in another question here that categories and overriding methods is discouraged, so maybe I am wrong all along? What is the canonical way of achieving what I would like to achieve? I can use a custom UIViewController subclass, and have all other controllers derive from it, but this will break as soon as I have controllers with differing requirements, and hence multiple base classes. In other languages I would use mixins, for example, and I think Objective-c categories are their counterpart?

Answer (score 2):

[Categories](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocCategories.html) are used to add additional methods to the class but not for overriding.

I think you can create a UIViewController subclass that overrides the method you mentioned and use this subclass as the super class of all your view controller so as to eliminate duplicate codes.

Secondly, you can use [class_replaceMethod](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/class_replaceMethod) or [method_exchangeImplementations](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/method_exchangeImplementations) to replace / exchange the implementation of the method you mentioned. But it would be dangerous.

Comment: The thing is that I read somewhere that a category can override methods, for example here: http://macdevelopertips.com/objective-c/objective-c-categories.html. So you are saying it is not possible? (Would make sense, as it doesn't work for me, but I thought 'I was doing things wrong', as Steve Jobs would have probably put it.)

Comment: In the past, apple documentation mentioned "When a category overrides an inherited method, the method in the category can, as usual, invoke the inherited implementation via a message to super. However, if a category overrides a method that already existed in the category's class, there is no way to invoke the original implementation". But it's no longer in the doc nowadays. So can we assume it's now allowed anymore?